# I want to know what settings should I make in my event

Tags: canon

The Event will be in an open area at night...and I will be there to take photos for the people with each other..I think that their won't be much light there...please I want to know how to take the best photos in that event with my camera canon 1200d because I am still a beginner photographer..please help me!

Comment: "...please I want to know how to take the best photos in that event..." Hire a photographer who knows how to shoot in such conditions and understands what kind of camera gear is and isn't up to the challenge of such a situation. Shooting moving subjects in very little light is pretty much the most challenging type of photography there is, both in terms of the photographer's knowledge, experience, and skill and the gear needed.  Your question is almost like asking, "I just bought a Toyota Camry. How can I compete in the 24 Hours of Le Mans (at night, in the rain, etc.) with it?

Comment: @Michael, no need to scare him/her off for life! It's not quite a Toyota Camry in the 24 Hours of Le Mans :) I get the impression that the aim here is just some basic posed photos of people at a social event.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably get the best results given the circumstances by just using the green "Auto" mode or the "Night Portrait" mode. The reason that these modes exist is for situations just like yours.